# Windows 7 Explorer suddenly dies and TaskManager not responding

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

Since two days ago I have the problem that my Explorer suddenly dies. It happens approx. 30 minutes after the computer has been started. The Taskbar vanishes all other applications remain on screen and only the application which has focus throws an error (it is already running for a while and it doensn't matter which application).

[image]

When I afterwards try to CRTL+ALT+DEL to start the Task-Manager I get the following error

[image]

When restarting the system (no cold restart) I get the following error

[image]

At this point pulling the plug is the only solution. When starting the system again windows complains that is hasn't been shut down correctly but starts without any problems.
I first throught of corrupt windows files and run [sfc /scannow](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system) without any results

[image]

I also rand the Windows internal memory test which did not find any problems and also a S.M.A.R.T. HDD test did not find any problems.

So my system can only be used for about 30 minutes before the explorer crashes. Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: See this [article](https://neosmart.net/wiki/0xc000000e_selected_entry_could_not_be_loaded/).

Comment: maybe the HDD is about to die. Check it with HDD diag tool.